Proving existence of a linear combination by using partial fraction decomposition
For $n$ integer and $t>1$, we define $A_n(t)$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
A_n(t) = \frac1{(1+t)^n} + \frac1{(1-t)^n}
\end{align*}
Now, we want to compute $A_n(t)\cdot A_p(t)$:
\begin{align*}
A_n(t) \cdot A_p(t) &= 
 \Big[ \frac1 {(1+t)^{n}} +  \frac1{(1-t)^{n}} \Big] \cdot 
 \Big[ \frac1 {(1+t)^{p}} +  \frac1{(1-t)^{p}} \Big] \\
   &=  \frac1 {(1+t)^{n+p}} + \frac1{(1-t)^{n+p}} + \frac1{(1+t)^{n}(1-t)^{p}} + \frac1{(1+t)^{p}(1-t)^{n}}  \\
   &=  A_{n+p}(t)  + \frac1{(1+t)^{n}(1-t)^{p}} + \frac1{(1+t)^{p}(1-t)^{n}}  \\
\end{align*}
Then we define:
\begin{align*}
\Delta_{n,p}(t) &= A_n(t) \cdot A_p(t)  -  A_{n+p}(t) \\
                &= \frac1{(1+t)^{n}(1-t)^{p}} + \frac1{(1+t)^{p}(1-t)^{n}}
\end{align*}
"Numerical evidence" seems to tell that $\Delta_{n,p}(t)$ is a linear combination of some $A_i(t)$ for $1\le i \le \max(n,p)$.
Here are two examples:
\begin{align*}
\Delta_{1,2}(t) &=  \frac{1}{2} A_1(t) + \frac{1}{2} A_2(t)   \\
\Delta_{2,5}(t) &= \frac{5}{32} A_1(t) + \frac{5}{32} A_2(t) + \frac{3}{16} A_3(t) + \frac{1}{4} A_4(t) + \frac{1}{4} A_5(t)  
\end{align*}
Question:  how to prove that $\Delta_{n,p}(t)$ is actualy a linear combination of some $A_i(t)$ and how to find the coefficients of this
linear combination ?
The fact that such a linear combination exists is not obvious at first glance. My idea so far has been to use partial fraction composition but I have not managed to use it properly for this  problem.

We just need two observations. First, $\Delta_{n, p}(t)$ is a rational function with denominator $(1 + t)^{\text{max}(n, p)}(1 - t)^{\text{max}(n, p)}$ and a numerator of strictly smaller degree, so it has a partial fraction decomposition expressing it uniquely as a linear combination of $\frac{1}{(1 + t)^i}, \frac{1}{(1 - t)^j}$ for $i, j \le \text{max}(n, p)$. This is a completely general fact about partial fraction decompositions.
Second, the functions $A_n$ are all even: $A_n(t) = A_n(-t)$. So the same is true of $\Delta_{n, p}(t)$, and by the uniqueness of partial fraction decomposition it follows that the coefficients of $\frac{1}{(1 - t)^i}$ and $\frac{1}{(1 + t)^i}$ must agree. This says exactly that $\Delta_{n, p}$ must be a linear combination of $A_i$ as desired.
Finding the coefficients seems a bit annoying (although maybe there is some nice approach); in general it's a bit annoying to express the coefficients of partial fraction decomposition when the denominator has repeated roots. But maybe you can find a nice recursion in $n$ and $p$.

Good point for the existence ! I keep trying to find the coefficients of the linear combination.

Here is a possible answer for the computation of the coefficients of the linear combination.
In the following, we suppose that $n=p+e$ with $e\ge 0$. Then we have:
\begin{align}
\label{E1}
\Delta_{n,p}(t) &= \frac1{(1+t)^{p+e}(1-t)^{p}} + \frac1{(1+t)^{p}(1-t)^{p+e}}  \nonumber \\
                &= \frac {(1+t)^e + (1-t)^e}  {(1+t)^{n}(1-t)^{n}} 
\end{align}
Since  the existence of the linear combination is established according to Qiaochu Yuan's answer,
we can write the following where $a_{n,p}(i)$ are the coefficients to be found:
\begin{align}
\label{E2}
\Delta_{n,p}(t) &= \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{n,p}(i) \cdot A_{i}(t)  \nonumber \\
   &= \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{n,p}(i) \cdot \Bigg( \frac1{(1+t)^i} + \frac1{(1-t)^i} \Bigg) \nonumber \\
   &= \frac1{(1+t)^n\,(1-t)^n} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{n,p}(i) \Big( (1-t)^{n}\,(1+t)^{n-i} + (1-t)^{n-i}\,(1+t)^{n}    \Big)           
\end{align}
So by identification, we can write:
\begin{align}
\label{E3}
{(1+t)^e + (1-t)^e} =  \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{n,p}(i) \Big( (1-t)^{n}\,(1+t)^{n-i} + (1-t)^{n-i}\,(1+t)^{n}   \Big)
\end{align}
On the left side, we have:
\begin{align}
(1+t)^e + (1-t)^e &= \sum_{k=0}^{e} {e \choose k} \, \Big( 1+(-1)^k \Big) \, t^k  
\end{align}
and on the right side:
\begin{align*}
(1-t)^{n}\,(1+t)^{n-i}  &= \Bigg[ \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} (-t)^k \Bigg] \cdot  \Bigg[\sum_{k=0}^{n-i} {n-i \choose k} t^k \Bigg] \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^{2\,n-i}  \beta_{n,i}(k) \cdot t^k
\end{align*}
with
\begin{align*}
\beta_{n,i}(k) = \sum_{u=0}^{k} (-1)^u \cdot {n \choose u} \cdot {n-i \choose k-u} 
\end{align*}
and similarly
\begin{align*}
(1+t)^{n}\,(1-t)^{n-i}  &= \sum_{k=0}^{2\,n-i}  \beta_{n,i}(k) \cdot (-1)^k \cdot t^k
\end{align*}
Finally, we get:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{e} {e \choose k} \, \Big( 1+(-1)^k \Big) \, t^k &=
 \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{n,p}(i) 
 \Bigg[ 
 \sum_{k=0}^{2\,n-i}  \beta_{n,i}(k) \cdot (1+(-1)^k) \cdot t^k
 \Bigg] \\
  &= \Bigg[ \sum_{k=0}^{2\,n} \Big[ \sum_{i=0}^{n} \beta_{n,i}(k) \cdot a_{n,p}(i) \Big] \cdot (1+(-1)^k) \cdot t^k\Bigg] \,+\, R
\end{align*}
where $R$ contains other terms not useful here. Indeed, this equation leads to the following linear system:
\begin{equation*}
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
\beta_{n,0}(0) & \beta_{n,1}(0) & ... & \beta_{n,n}(0) \\
\beta_{n,0}(2) & \beta_{n,1}(2) & ... & \beta_{n,n}(2) \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
\beta_{n,0}(2n) & \beta_{n,1}(2n) & ... & \beta_{n,n}(2n) 
\end{array}
\right]
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n,p}(0) \\  a_{n,p}(1)\\ ... \\ a_{n,p}(n)
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2\,{e \choose 0} \\  2\,{e \choose 2} \\ ... \\ 2\,{e \choose 2n}
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation*}
Here is a small test with gp/pari for $n=5$ and $p=2$:
beta(n,i,k) =  (1+(-1)^k) * sum(u=0,k, (-1)^u*binomial(n,u)*binomial(n-i,k-u));

[n,p]=[5,2];  
M = matrix (n+1,n+1,x,y, beta(n,y-1,2*(x-1)));
v = vector (n+1, x, 2*binomial((n-p),2*(x-1)));
a = matsolve (M, v~)

which returns [0, 5/32, 5/32, 3/16, 1/4, 1/4]~ as expected.
Although this linear system allows to find the coefficients, it doesn't provide a really simple way to do this and maybe there is a better approach yet to be found.
However, an interesting observation can be done: we define $M_n$ as the matrix where each row $p$ holds the $a_{n,p}(i)$ coefficients (for $p$ from $n$ to $1$). For instance, $M_5$ is as follows:
[35/128 35/128 15/64 5/32 1/16]
[35/128 35/128 15/64 5/32 1/16]
[ 15/64  15/64  7/32 3/16  1/8]
[  5/32   5/32  3/16  1/4  1/4]
[  1/16   1/16   1/8  1/4  1/2]

that can be computed with the following gp/pari code:
MM(n) = 
{
  sv=vector(n,x,0);
  forstep (p=n,1,-1,  e=n-p; 
    M = matrix (n+1,n+1,x,y, beta(n,y-1,2*(x-1))); 
    v = vector (n+1, x, 2*binomial(e,2*(x-1)));  
    tmp = matsolve (M, v~); 
    sv[p] = vector (n,x,tmp[x+1]); 
  );
  return (matrix (n,n, x, y, sv[n-x+1][y]));
}

Then, one can observe that the kernel of such a matrix seems to be related to the Omega polynomials, which could maybe provide insight to get a better expression for the $a$ coefficients. For instance, the kernel for $M_{15}$ is:
[       -1 1        0 0        0 0      0 0      0 0   0 0   0 0 0]
[        2 0       -3 1        0 0      0 0      0 0   0 0   0 0 0]
[      -16 0       20 0       -5 1      0 0      0 0   0 0   0 0 0]
[      272 0     -336 0       70 0     -7 1      0 0   0 0   0 0 0]
[    -7936 0     9792 0    -2016 0    168 0     -9 1   0 0   0 0 0]
[   353792 0  -436480 0    89760 0  -7392 0    330 0 -11 1   0 0 0]
[-22368256 0 27595776 0 -5674240 0 466752 0 -20592 0 572 0 -13 1 0]

